# How to make combination of two array without duplicate records and cross duplicate remove

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, database, combinations

```
$files = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$other = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

foreach($files as $k => $file){
    foreach($other as $key => $value){
        $data = [
            'column1' => $file,
            'column2' => $value,
        ];
        if($file == $value){
            return false
        }else{
            \DB::table('abed')->insert($data);
        }
    }
}
```

How to make combination of two array without duplicate records and cross duplicate remove

DB insert like that

```
|column1 |  column2 | 
|------- |  ------- |
|   a    |  b       |       
|   a    |  c       |
|   a    |  d       |
|   a    |  e       |
|   a    |  f       |
|   b    |  a       |
|   b    |  c       |
|   b    |  d       |
|   b    |  e       |
|   b    |  f       |
|   c    |  a       |
|   c    |  b       |
|   c    |  d       |
|   c    |  e       |
|   c    |  f       |
|   d    |  a       |
|   d    |  b       |
|   d    |  c       |
|   d    |  e       |
|   d    |  f       |
|   e    |  a       |
|   e    |  b       |
|   e    |  c       |
|   e    |  d       |
|   e    |  f       |
|   f    |  a       |
|   f    |  b       |
|   f    |  c       |
|   f    |  d       |
|   f    |  e       |
```

I want like this DB insert

```
|   a   |   b    |          
|   a   |   c    |
|   a   |   d    |
|   a   |   e    |
|   a   |   f    |
|   b   |   c    |
|   b   |   d    |
|   b   |   e    |
|   b   |   f    |
|   c   |   d    |
|   c   |   e    |
|   c   |   f    |
|   d   |   e    |
|   d   |   f    |
|   e   |   f    |
```

Comment: This [mcve] leaves much to the imagination.  Will your input arrays be identical? Will corresponding elements share indexes/values? We don't know how your input may vary.  Do we even need to use two arrays? Can we just "double" a solitary array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `in_array()`, refer to the below code :

```
$files = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$other = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

foreach($files as $k => $file){
  $parrentArray[] = $file;
  foreach($other as $key => $value){
    $data = [
        'column1' => $file,
        'column2' => $value,
    ];
    if(in_array($value, $parrentArray) == false){
        \DB::table('abcd')->insert($data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `return` is certainly incorrect.

Comment: you can skip the return, and write only the else condition.  if false then insert other wise loop will continue to the next value.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Vaibhav try this,
Hope this will helpful for you.
Also I change in execute query only once instead of execute in loop.

```
$files = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$other = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$data = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
{
    for($j = $i; $j < count($other); $j++)
    {
        if($files[$i] != $other[$j])
        {
            array_push($data,['column1' => $files[$i], 'column2' => $other[$j]]);
        }
    }   
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
\DB::table('abcd')->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this another example

| a | b |
| a | c | | a | d | | a | e | | a | f | | b | c | | b | d | | b | e | | b | f |

```
$files = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$other = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$data = [];

for ($i=0;$i< count($files) ; $i++)
{
    $counter = $i > 0 ? $i + 1 : 1;
    for ($j=$counter;$j< count($other) ; $j++)
    {
        $data[] = [
                'column1' => $files[$i],
                'column2' => $other[$j],
            ];
            
    }   
}
```

For another example ,

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| a | c |
| a | d |
| a | e |
| a | f |
| b | a |
| b | c |
| b | d |
| b | e |
| b | f |

```
$files = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$other = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$data = [];

for ($i=0;$i< count($files) ; $i++)
{
    for ($j=0;$j< count($other) ; $j++)
    {
        if($files[$i] != $other[$j]){
            $data[] = [
                    'column1' => $files[$i],
                    'column2' => $other[$j],
                ];
         
            }
    } 
}
```

Comment: In your logic it will get the "ab" and "ba". This is not the correct result he needed.

Comment: a compare b is right but b compare a not right